# Cannot open IIS 8 default site by private IP or localhost, yet IIS "browse" to by internal DNS works

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm getting a "HTTP 404 Not Found" when I enter the server's LAN IP (http://192.168.1.x - which the site has bindings for) or simply localhost. However, in IIS 8 I can successfully browse to http://Server.MyDomain.com and everythign works as intended. The static DNS A record already exists and was created for the hostname before I installed IIS 8 role.

What could be the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: I suppose this was better suited for ServerFault, but at any rate, I found the solution: reinstalling IIS role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling IIS role resolved this issue.